# Azure Scheduler - pass date parameter

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler

I want to pass `current date` parameter to Azure Scheduler action URL when it executes.

For example, 
`https://<server_ip>/some/job/endpoint?startdate={0}&enddate={1}` 
Where the placeholder will pass the current date and if possible to do some simple evaluation to add 1 day to startdate for enddate.

Is there a way to do this using the Azure Scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not since there is a [open vote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/230896-scheduler/suggestions/5812428-azure-scheduler-support-for-variables) for supporting variables for Azure Scheduler. However, you could use Azure function with a time based trigger that performs your request including the date.